# Find Weibull parameters from incomplete sample

Tags: missing-data, goodness-of-fit, weibull-distribution

I have samples with known number of missing elements (expressed as NaN's) that range from 10%-90% missing. The same function, Weibull, works for all cases.

My question is then, how can I find/converge to the "real" parameters of the model, having incomplete samples??

Thanks!

Comment: Can you say more about the missing values? In what way are they missing? (For example, if you're observing time to failure and you have observations that you can no longer observe before failure, sometimes people think of that as '*missing*' though in fact we'd call it '*censored*'). Do you only have a single variable? Is the fact that it's missing related to its value? (e.g. you can't observe very large or very small values because of a measuring instrument) Is it related to the value of another variable? Might it plausibly be "missing at random" or "missing completely  at random"?

Comment: It's wind speeds recorded every 6 hours. A typical sequence has, e.g. 20 or 30 elements, but for some reason, (NOAAs crew couldn't get there in time, or the device broke), some of the specific instances weren't recorded. So a sequence looks like [90 95 95 NA 80 90 NA 60...]. Many studies have shown that the Weibul model works consistently well for wind speeds, so that's why I adopt it a priori.

Comment: Both "couldn't get there in time" and "device broke" sound like they might be potentially related to wind speed (since high wind speed might complicate travel, and break devices); this may be an important issue.

Comment: Yes that's a good point actually. But I forgot to mention that if the storm happened a long time ago, or happened outside of the US, they're more likely to have NaNs as well. Moreover, the measurements are sometimes made by aircraft at 3000 meters high, and they're usually interested in not missing the high-wind storms. So there's a lot of factors involved.

Comment: The question then becomes the degree to which you might either be prepared to assume some form of missing at random, or to try to figure out whether some missings might relate to observation size. Is this just a bunch of time series? Are there other variables you want to include that would be predictors of the wind speed?

Comment: Yes, a bunch of time series. Not at this time, I can't use predictors because there's so many variables involved and the uncertainty is not justified. I guess I'm inclined to assume some form of MAR.

Comment: Are the missing values only at one end of each series, or can you have a series with some gaps in them?

Comment: Both, sometimes gaps, sometimes at one or both ends. Also sometimes there's many Nan's and then a number, e.g. [90 90 85 NA NA NA NA NA 85 85 .....]

Comment: So ... parameter estimation in univariate Weibull time series with internal missing values. Outside my area of expertise, but I'd be inclined to specify some model for how the distributions relate over time and (probably) start with something like E-M. An alternative might be some form of MCMC. I don't know enough abut wind behavior to begin to suggest a suitable model though.

Comment: Cool. I'm much farther outside than you I guess :). So, which model could I think of for relating pdfs over time? How could I use the EM to start?

Comment: How can I answer the first without knowing anything about the behavior of wind? Are there existing models that might give some clue (not necessarily Weibull). In the absence of a model, advice about something like EM would be very general (no more use than just looking up the algorithm on wikipedia or something similar).

Comment: Well, I'm not sure about any models. Probably within some Poisson processes scheme, but not sure. Could you think of another situation where the approach you suggest, or similar, was used? Maybe if I see/study such a methodology at work, used in another context, might give me a clue of what to do in this problem.

Comment: No, sorry. I guess you'll have to get someone with more of a clue than I have. But at least some of the details of your question are clearer.